# Enviar dados do RecycleView para Activity

Tags: android, edittext

Bem, sou nova no desenvolvimento Android e gostaria de saber como passo o valor da opção selecionada no Recycleview para um EditText que está em outra Activity

Comment: Tente formular melhor a sua pergunta, colocando código do que você já tem feito e onde está tendo dificuldades. Assim, fica mais facil alguem se dispor a te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso. Primeiro você precisa receber o evento de clique no `RecyclerView` na `Activity` atual e depois você pode passar esse valor no `Intent` para uma outra `Activity`.

Para detectar o evento de clique em um item da `RecyclerView` você pode criar um listener dentro do seu `ViewHolder` e utilizar uma interface para comunicar de volta os dados para a Activity

Aqui está um exemplo do adapter da `RecyclerView`

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> items;

    // Referência para o listener obtido no 'setOnClickListener'
    private OnItemClickListener clickListener;

    public ItemAdapter(List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        // Aqui você infla o layout de cada view
        return new ViewHolder(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        String item = items.get(position);

        viewHolder.bind(item);
        // Aqui você faz o bind entre a view e o item da lista atual
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    // Método utilizado para comunicar o evento de clique de volta para a Activity
    public void setOnClickListener(OnItemClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        String item;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // Criando o evento de clique no item da lista e repassando o evento de volta para o listener
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clickListener.onItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }

        void bind(String item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }
}


// Interface utilizada para criar o contrato entre Adapter/Activity
interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(String item);
}
```

E você faria isso na `Activity`:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(items);

        adapter.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(String item) {
                // Agora você tem o item clicado e pode mandar ele para outra Activity

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OutraActivity.this);
                intent.putExtra("item", item);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Outro link para referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick